# How to get boost wdirectory_iterator to return UTF32 on the Mac

Tags: c++, macos, boost, utf

**directory_iterator** returns UTF8 using both Visual Studio and Xcode as expected.

**wdirectory_iterator**, however, returns UTF16 using Visual Studio, and UTF8 using Xcode, despite returning a wchar_t string.

What can I change to get wdirectory_iterator to return UTF32?

An answer to a [question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810677/what-utf-format-should-boost-wdirectoryiterator-return) suggests that changing the locale might be required, however according to 'locale -a' the only locales available are

en_GB, en_GB.ISO8859-1, en_GB.ISO8859-15, en_GB.US-ASCII, en_GB.UTF-8
All are 8 bit, with the possible exception of en_GB

I tried en_GB in case it might not be 8 bit, but this causes boost::filesystem::exists to throw a boost::filesystem::wpath::to_external conversion exception.

Comment: But I am getting UTF-8 back, not 16 or 32, and all references I have found indicate the Mac wchar_t is UTF-32. Perhaps I will have to convert from UTF-8, but I'd like to be sure I'm not missing something more standard first.

Comment: Sorry David, I was wrong. On Mac, the native encoding for `wchar_t` depends on the combination of endian-ness and size of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Try http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wdirectory_iterator` is a typedef for `basic_directory_iterator<wpath>`. `wpath` is a typedef for `basic_path<std::wstring, wpath_traits>`.

Similarily to what is done in `std::basic_filebuf`, A `basic_path` uses an "internal" encoding to represent names to the program, and an "external" encoding to interact with the platform's filesystem. Conversion between these encodings is done like in `std::basic_filebuf`, by using the `std::codecvt` of the locale imbued on it.

So, names are obtained by the iterator from the operating system in the system's encoding (that's the "external" encoding), and converted to the "internal" encoding with `Traits::to_internal`. To perform the desired conversion, you can thus:

- Call `wpath_traits::imbue()` "early" in your program, passing it a locale with a codecvt facet performing UTF8->UTF32 conversion
- Or define and use you own Traits class, where you implement `to_internal` to perform a UTF8->UTF32 conversion